# Call not default object constructor for each object uniquely when creating a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to create a vector of objects and would like the not default constructor to be called uniquely for each object in the vector. I have an simplified example below.

In my example I have an object with two constructors, default (no args) and non-default (1 arg). When I initialized a vector of size 10 using the default constructor (v1), the constructor gets called 10 times (as can be seen by the random numbers). However, when I try to initialize a vector with the objects non-default constructor (v2), the object constructor is called once and this object is copied to the remaining elements in the vector (x is no longer many different random numbers).

Is it possible to initialize a vector of N objects so that each objects non-default constructor is called for each object?

Example Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Obj {
    int x;

    Obj() {
        x = rand() % 5;
    }

    Obj(int max_x) {
        x = rand() % max_x;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Obj> v1(10);     // Default constructor
    std::vector<Obj> v2(10, 5);  // Non-Default Constructor

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        std::cout << v1[i].x << ", " << v2[i].x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3, 2
1, 2
2, 2
0, 2
3, 2
0, 2
1, 2
2, 2
4, 2
1, 2
```

**Solution**

The following function can be used to return an object vector where the not default constructor is called of each object.

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>  std::vector<T> InitVector(const int n, Args ... args) {
     std::vector<T> vec;
     for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         vec.emplace_back(args ...);
     }
     return vec;
}
```

Comment: With uniform initialization, yes.

Comment: did you think about `srand(time(NULL))`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether this could be a solution but you could overload the copy constructor to do the intended construction. (This observation is new for me. Have to dig deeper where it could be an issue on our side...)

Comment: Don't use `rand()`, look into `<random>`.

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) to complement @Qubit's comment, though unrelated to the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the quick replies. In the end, the best solution to my particular problem was to create a vector initialization function (using emplace_back as people suggested) that would return the desired result. I need to initialize a lot of object vectors and would prefer them to be immutable, so this generic solution is probably best for my use case.

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>

 template <typename T, typename ... Args>
 std::vector<T> InitVector(const int n, Args ... args) {
     std::vector<T> vec;
     for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         vec.emplace_back(args ...);
     }
     return vec;
 }

 struct Obj {
     int x;

     Obj() {
         x = rand() % 5;
     }

     Obj(int max_x) {
         x = rand() % max_x;
     }
 };

 int main() {
     const std::vector<Obj> v1(10);
     const std::vector<Obj> v2 = InitVector<Obj>(10, 5);

     for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
         std::cout << v1[i].x << ", " << v2[i].x << std::endl;
     }
 }
```

Result:

```
3, 2
1, 2
2, 0
0, 4
3, 3
0, 1
1, 0
2, 1
4, 2
1, 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Here're two workarounds.

1. Use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

   ```
   std::vector<Obj> v2{5, 5, 5, ...};
   ```
2. Use [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to insert the elements later.

   ```
   std::vector<Obj> v2;
   v2.reserve(10);
   for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
       v2.emplace_back(5);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure whether this could be a solution but you could overload the copy constructor to do the intended construction.

I tried the idea with overloading the copy constructor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Obj {
    const int max_x;
    int x;

    Obj(): Obj(5) { }

    Obj(int max_x): max_x(max_x), x(rand() % max_x) { }

    Obj(const Obj &obj): Obj(obj.max_x) { }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Obj> v1(10);     // Default constructor
    std::vector<Obj> v2(10, 5);  // Non-Default Constructor

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        std::cout << v1[i].x << ", " << v2[i].x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3, 2
1, 0
2, 4
0, 3
3, 1
0, 0
1, 1
2, 2
4, 1
1, 1
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9602b45659b369b8)</kbd>

It's better but the draw back is the additional member in `struct Obj`. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
std::vector<Obj> v2;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v2),10, [](){return 5;});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think these lines can help you

```
std::vector<Obj> v2;
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
    Obj s(5); // Non-Default Constructor
   v2.push_back(s); 
}
```

Comment: This answer likely won't garner upvotes because you are using `push_back` instead of `emplace_back` and are not reserving the known number of elements beforehand.